# Cancel button click event while executing heavy method in C#

Tags: c#, events

I want to cancel button click event while executing any heavy method in C#.
Lets say there is following method and event:

```
private void Submit()
{
    //This method requires 5 seconds and it is blocking method   
}
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Some code here
}
```

When I click on button while executing Submit method, the button click event does not fire, instead of it fires after completed the execution of Submit method.

I want to cancel this event when clicked while executing the Submit method.
I can not disable this button as my application contains many of such buttons.
I also want to prevent all events to be fired that is initiated during execution of Submit method if possible and allow all events to be fired after execution of Submit method.

Pls suggest any solution or workaround to achieve the about task.

Comment: You can call your Submit() asynchronously so that it won't block the UI.

Comment: In addition, your long running code in Submit() must regularly check if it's been canceled and react accordingly

Comment: I want to call Submit() synchronously and cancel all events during execution.

Answer (score 2):

If you start a new task using async, you will be able to call the cancel method whilst executing the Submit.

```
private async Task Submit()
{
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
    {
        // Blocking code, network requests...
    });
}
```

Have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx for await async reference, and also Channel 5 has some great videos about it https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Three-Essential-Tips-for-Async

If you want to stop "Submit" whenever you trigger "Cancel", I would recommend using a CancellationEventSource to cancel the task, have a look:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

private CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

private async Task Submit()
{
    var cancellationToken = this.cancellationTokenSource.Token;
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
    {
        cancellationToken .ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        // Blocking code, network requests...

    }, this.cancellationTokenSource.Token); 
}

private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
}
```

Have a look at this msdn article on CancellationTokenSource and Task https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396(v=vs.110).aspx

Edit 1:

> I don't want to stop the Submit() any more. I want to cancel the event
>   during execution of Submit() and allow event to be fired after
>   completion of the Submit()

Create a Task and await for it to finish:

```
private Task submitTask;

private void Submit()
{
    this.submitTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
    {
        // Some Code
    } 
}
private async void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // Awaiting will prevent blocking your UI    
    await this.submitTask;

    // Some Code    
}
```

Comment: I don't want to stop the Submit() any more. I want to cancel the event during execution of Submit() and allow event to be fired after completion of the Submit()

Answer (score 0):

```
               delegate void submitdelegate();
                public partial class Form1 : Form
                  {
                   public Form1()
                        {
                          InitializeComponent();
                         }
                   IAsyncResult ia;
              private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                submitdelegate sd=Submit;
              ia=sd.BeginInvoke(()=>{},null,null);

                 }
                 private void Submit()
                {

                   }

    void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if(ia.IsCompleted)
       {//run all the things you want here
          }
        }
```

creating an instance in Iasyncresult will give you wether the delegate finished executioin.
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=634

Comment: Actually i want to allow event to be  fired after execution of Submit()

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Task` to achieve that.

```
CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken _ct;

private void Submit()
{
     _ct = cancellationTokenSource.Token;
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
      _ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
      //your code here
    }, _ct);


}
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Some code here
   _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
}
```

`CancellationToken` is an object that allows you to send to 'Task' information that the task should be cancelled. Additionally inside your `Task` make sure you are `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` to make sure that this task will be stopped.

In my example button_click is the cancel button.

More information you can possibly find here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is to prevent the button(s) from having any effect if a call to `Submit()` is currently active.

**To do so:**

(1) Wrap the call to `Submit()` inside an `async` method that calls `Submit()` as a separate task:

```
private async Task SubmitAsync()
{
    await Task.Run(() => Submit());
}
```

(2) Add to the class a boolean field that will be used to check if `Submit()` is currently executing:

```
private bool submitIsActive = false;
```

(3) Change your button click handler(s) to be `async` and check the `submitIsActive` flag before awaiting `SubmitAsync()`:

```
private async void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!submitIsActive)
    {
        submitIsActive = true;
        await SubmitAsync();
        submitIsActive = false;
    }
}
```

At first glance you might think that there's a race condition where `submitIsActive` is set to true in one thread, but checked in a different thread. This is not so because the `button_Click()` method will only ever be called from the UI thread.

Also note that this approach does NOT allow you to cancel a call to `Submit()` - but I don't think you were asking for that.

Answer (score -2):

What about unsubscribing the buttons from their click events for the duration of the  Submit() method? Too many buttons?

Comment: Basic UI event handling really shouldn't be messed with, no. Much cleaner to do such checks in the event handler.